# Python homework - take list of times and print the fastest time

Tags: python

On MPL the question is "You're a swimmer, and you want to compare all of your race times to find the fastest one. Write a program that continuously takes race times as doubles from standard input, until the input is "no more races," at which point it should print out the time of your fastest race."

My code works in python but on MPL it doesn't work for some reason. Here's my code

```
input("")
list1=[]
while input("")!=str("no more races,"):
    list1.append(float(input("")))
    if input("")=="no more races,":
         print(min(list1))
```

Comment: `"no more races,"` is already a string; there's no need to pass it to the `str` function (which simply returns a copy of its string argument).

Comment: You are taking input _three times_ per loop iteration, only adding one of them to the list, and checking the other two for the stopping condition. It makes sense that it's not accepted as an answer.

Comment: You do realize that each call to `input()` is asking for input another time, right?  You can't make a reference to what the user already typed by using `input("")`

Comment: And this code could just be `print(min(map(float, iter(input, 'no more races'))))`. Note the lack of a comma after `races`, as I would bet that they're using ordinary English quoting syntax, which puts the comma within the quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `input` multiple times, rather than simply saving the value of each string as you type it. (The first call to `input` is particularly useless.) You could start with the relatively straightforward code

```
list1 = []
race_time = input("Enter a race time: ")
while race_time != "no more races":
    list1.append(float(race_time))
    race_time = input("Enter a race time: ")
print(min(list1))
```

but you might find it slightly annoying to have to call `input` in two places. Instead, you might use an "infinite" loop which you explicitly break out of (which is the Python pattern for a loop that will execute at least one time)

```
list1 = []
while True:
    race_time = input("Enter a race time: ")
    if race_time == "no more races":
        break
    list1.append(float(race_time))
print(min(list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct structure looks like this:

```
list1 = []
while True:
    i = input("")  # read input only once per iteration
    if i == "no more races,":
        break
    list1.append(float(i))
print(min(list1))
```

In your code, you read new input three times per iteration: 1. in while-condition check, 2. in list-appending, 3. in break-check.
However, you want to do all those things with the same input.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge list, and all you care about is the fastest time, you might be better off not storing the whole list.

```
race_time = float(input(""))  # this is supposing at least one race time
minimum = race_time

while race_time != "no more races,":
    race_time = float(race_time)
    minimum = min(minimum, race_time)

print(minimum)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code takes input from the user until the input is 'no more races'. Then it sorts all the elements of the list to arrange them in the increasing order. Now finding the fastest or second fastest or even the last is very simple. To find the fastest race just print the element 0 of the sorted list.

```
l = []
while True:
    i = input("Enter time of race")
    if i == "no more races":
        break
    l.append(float(i))
order=sorted(l)
print (order[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=[]
x=0
cap=' ' 
cap=input( )
while cap!='no more races':
     x=float(cap)
     list1.append(x)
     cap=input( )
print(min(list1))
```

You have to put your first input statement before the while loop in order to capture the exit condition without generating an error message from trying to convert a text string to a float.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct answer for MPL to accept:

```
list1 = []

while True:

    race_time = input("")
    if race_time == "no more races":
        break
    list1.append(float(race_time))
print(min(list1))
```

You're welcome, this took me forever to figure out.